# Using Spring MVC with freemarker as view technology, how to pass data from server side to javascript?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm working on a project with spring 3 MVC and I have the need to some values from El element to javascript. Since I'm using freemarker I haven't been able to find a way to do that.
I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Id = <%= ${id} %> // something of a sort.this is just to illustrate
</script>
```

Can any one shed a light on my issue please? Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What doesn't work? Why are you using JSP syntax inside a FreeMarker template?

Comment: No not at all, i wrote the var stuff to express what i expect to do with freemarker. That is obviously JSP tag so , the question is really about how it's possible to passe data to javascript when view technology is Freemarker.thanks

Comment: Don't think of it as "passing data to JavaScript" -- you're providing a template with data, it doesn't matter at all what the context of the data is to FreeMarker -- it's all just placeholders.

Comment: Let me put it in more practical.Supposing i would like to use a grid say datatables or slickgrid and that for perfomance reason, i am able to load 30 out of 500 rows of the data on page load and planned to use the grid pagination to load the second and other pages based on use action after the page loaded.if you have that record as `model.addAttribute("userCollection", aCollection)` with my scenario in mind what would you do with `${userCollection}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found a little simple work arround. I passed it in a hidden field and access he val using

```
jQuery("#id").val()
```

working fine actually 
thanks